# Getting an empty list after appending strong numbers

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I am supposed to make list of strong numbers in a given range.
I've written a code for that where I define a function for strong number in which I take the number and append its digits into an empty `list(l1)`. Then using for loop I append the factorial of those digits in another empty `list(l2)`. Then I return `sum(l2)==given number`. I've tried this function for individual numbers and code runs perfectly and gives whether the number is strong or not.
But when i put this function in a for loop to find which are strong numbers in given range by appending the function to another empty list. The resultant comes out to be empty instead of giving list of strong numbers.

My code is:
`

```
import math
s=int(input("enter end range: "))
l1=[]
l2=[]
l3=[]
def strong(x):
    for i in str(x):
        l1.append(int(i))
    for i in l1:
        l2.append(math.factorial(i))
    return(sum(l2)==int(x))        
for i in range(0,s+1):
    if strong(i)==True:
        l3.append(i)
print(l3)
```

`

```
The input and output are supposed to be as follows:
enter end range: 150
list: [1, 2, 145]
 
But I get:
enter end range: 150
list: []
I get an empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

The declarations for `l1` and `l2` should be local to the function:

```
import math
s=int(input("enter end range: "))
l3=[]
def strong(x):
    l1=[]
    l2=[]
    for i in str(x):
        l1.append(int(i))
    for i in l1:
        l2.append(math.factorial(i))
    return(sum(l2)==int(x))        
for i in range(0,s+1):
    if strong(i)==True:
        l3.append(i)
print(l3)
```

**Output:-**

```
enter end range: 150
[1, 2, 145]
```